# How should I be adding a single item to Core Data? insertIntoManagedContext or insertNewObjectForEntityForName?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I just want to add a single `Color` object to my Core Data store. How would I best do this?

I can either do:

```
Color *color = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Color" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
```

Or:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Color" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
Color *color = [[Color alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]
```

When would I use one over the other? (Or, why would I want to use a 2-line solution over a 1-line solution with arguably better clarity?)

Comment: I prefer the first because it is shorter. It really does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods are equivalent. In the interest of brevity, the first is preferable.